# Unity integration for Oculus error: DllNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' was thrown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

.

I have already imported the `Unity Free integration for Oculus` package through `Assets` -> `Import Package` but I still get the following error message when I run a simple program:

```
DllNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' was thrown.
Ovr.Hmd.Detect () (at Assets/OVR/Scripts/OvrCapi.cs:1361)
```

I don't actually have an Oculus hooked up, and the code snippet that checks this is the following:

```
void Start()
{
    if ( Ovr.Hmd.Detect() > 0 )
    {
        Debug.Log( "Oculus Rift HMD detected! " + OVRManager.capiHmd.GetString( Hmd.OVR_KEY_USER, "" ) );
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log( "No Oculus Rift detected..." );
    }
}
```

Line 1361 that the err msg is pointing at is the following:

```
public static int Detect()
{
    return ovrHmd_Detect();
}
```

But when I replace `Ovr.Hmd.Detect()` with `ovrHmd_Detect()` it is highlighted red.

What am I doing wrong?

.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well as the error message states, you are missing a dll. Which suggest to me that you did not correctly import the package.

When you import the OculusUnityIntegration.unitypackage into your Unity project you should end up with some files in the Assets/Plugins folder, one of which is the OculusPlugin.dll. Which in this case seems to be the one you are missing

Try re-importing the package and make sure you have all items. You can follow [this step by step guide](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?p=9969#p9969)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Oculus SDK in Unity Editor. You just need to install Oculus PC App. Restart may be required.

Answer (score -3):

Just build the application with Architecture "x86_64":

[image: Build Setting Window]